# Passing a field value in the URL

Tags: javascript, webix

Can I dynamically edit the url of the datatable depending on the value of the “Value” field of the search form in another file?
For example:

```
{ view:"text", label:"input data", value:"apple" }
```

In datatable.js

```
url: 'resource->/api/archive/apple'
```

Okay, I was told that I can send AJAX requests, but now I can't figure out how to get them correctly on another page

Sending:

```
webix.ajax().post('apples', get_form())
routie('apples')
```

In devtools I get the form value

[image]

I'm trying to get the formData value to substitute it in the URL

```
function get_data() {
    let result;
    webix.ajax("apples").then(function (data) {
        data = data.text();
        result = data;
    });
    return result;
}
```

URL

```
url: 'resource->/api/archive/all/'.concat(get_data()),
```

On the backend side, this controller works well, but I can't call it from the front side. I'm just learning frontend, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you further explain your concrete problem and give more context?

Comment: You can dynamically change URL. But where is the "Value" field located? another tab?

Comment: I'm using Spring as a backend framework, I have repositories that do database lookups and a controller that creates the appropriate model and passes in its view. For the frontend, I use webix, which has a datatable to display tabular data and can get data from the URL, and also has a form that will contain user input. The bottom line is to dynamically change the URL of the datatable in order to correctly issue data on request from the form.

Comment: @ITgoldman Yes. Datatable and User form they are different files

Comment: File is a confusing word in this context. You want to communicate between 2 pages. You need a server for that. This means ajax requests probably.

Comment: @ITgoldman Updated the question, maybe now it's clearer what I'm expecting

Answer (score 0):

In general, the way to do this is: When the value is changed (the *onChange* event), call *clearAll()* and *load(newUrl)* methods of the datatable. You cannot change the *url* property at runtime (well, you can, but it won't work).

As for different files, people usually build SPAs with Webix, so files here might be modules, not pages. Do you use Webix Jet? If yes, then communication between the form and the datatable can be done via the app event bus. If not, then they can communicate directly (import both files in some other file and do it there). If this is a multiple-page app, then yes, you do need some server side communication between them (maybe even with sockets).